# eXist-db (naming/renaming of collections and files)

Tags: exist-db

I am very new to eXist-db. At the moment, everything goes well, the only one problem is I can’t name or rename collections and files. If I try to create new collection, it is created but is named `undefined`, no matter what I fill in the window during creating. With files, it is the same—I can upload them but can’t rename them. (I am admin, rights are set well, as it seems.) The whole DB is installed in a custom directory, no admin rights were needed.

I am using the default dashboard (I am not trying do it via Java app).

Comment: Which version of eXist?

Comment: The latest stable, have just downloaded it. I think 2.2.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your results given your description. Could you post the step-by-step directions for reproducing your results? Perhaps there's something subtle you're doing that you're not describing.

Comment: Oh, it is quite simple:

Comment: Well, I have tried that again and it works properly only if I add another one collection. That means:
1) the first collection is always called 'undefined';
2) any new is called properly as I have chosen;
3) it is impossible to rename any of them later.

Comment: Step-by-step directions, please. Starting from "1. start the database and open the dashboard."

Comment: 1) open eXist-db from Win 7 shell;
2) open dashboard via icon in the notification area;
3) login;
4) open collections (Dashboard);
5) double click on "apps" collection;
6) click on "New collection";
7) fill in the name and press "Ok".
> new collection named "undefined" has been created
8) click on this collection and than click on "Edit owner, groups and perms..."
9) re-fill the "resource" name;
10) click to Ok.
> nothing had happened
11) click to "New Collection" again;
12) fill in the name;
13) click ok;
14) properly named new collection has been made.
> impossible to rename any of them

Comment: I've posted your report on exist-open, the eXist users mailing list: http://markmail.org/message/5pcx75yc325fh2dc. I'd welcome you to join at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open. Hopefully someone will be able to provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem , the only solution that I had found is download the file change the name and upload it again , try with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the java client. Select the resource and select rename from file menu.